# How To Get All Active Campaigns, Adsets, and Ads Starting Today Facebook Marketing/Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to query Facebook for all campaign, asset, and ad id's with their name and current spend, and whose start date is today. My current `GET` request inside of Graph API looks like this:

`act_xxxxxxx/ads?fields=name,campaign_id,adset_id,insights{spend}&filtering=[{'field':'adset.start_time','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'1667448000'},{'field':'adset.start_time','operator':'LESS_THAN','value':'1667534400'}]&limit=1000&date_preset=today`

Which which facebook returns
`{"data": [ { "name": "Ad Name","campaign_id": "xxxxxx", "adset_id": "xxxxxxx", "id": "xxxxxxx"}...`

I can confirm that the number of ads returned is equal to the number of active ads I have starting in that account today.

However, if you notice, there are no `insights` included, despite the fact all campaigns have spent hundreds today already.

In Graph API Explorer, I see this:
[image]

As you can see insights are greyed out, meaning the field is empty or disallowed.

I'm positive I have the proper permission on the ad account because when I remove the filtering within the query it returns spend values from prior campaigns (I can even set the start time minimum to yesterday rather than this morning at midnight and it will return yesterday's campaigns with spend).

So the issue here seems to be filtering, but I'm obviously not 100% sure, any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It takes a while for FB to collect, ingest the metrics and make it available for querying via insights API. In my experience, it takes a day at the max.